Azure DevOps Dashboard - Release Pipeline Overview should support YAML Pipelines
I want to display yaml pipeline's stage results & status in my Azure DevOps dashboard. But there is no ADO Dashboard widget available for this purpose.
There is a deployment / release pipeline overview widget but i can't use it for yaml pipeline.
So I just wanted to know if anyone is using any other way to achieve this ?
Deployment Status overview:

Example - Deployment Status sample widget:


Have you tried the extensions mentioned below? are they working for you? @PoluruKishoreBabu

Sorry, I can't try the following extensions in  my Azure DevOps Environment. It doesn't look maintained, so. But thanks for the suggestion

The two extensions can work fine and are not deprecated. @PoluruKishoreBabu

From the  Marketplace, you can find the following extensions for dashboard widgets that can meet you demands by search for the keywords "Pipeline overview":

YAML Release Pipeline Overview
Pipeline overview


You can install any of the two extensions into your Azure DevOps organization for use.
See below example as reference:

The results of runs for a pipeline.


Use the extension "YAML Release Pipeline Overview".


Use the extension "Pipeline overview".




